# Centos 5 Apache 2.2 configure with mod_wsgi (missing apxs folder)

Tags: centos5, apache-2.2, mod-wsgi

I have got a dedicated server and CENTOS 5,webmin and Apache 2.2 is already installed.
They installed Apache at `/usr/libexec/webmin/apache/` and it works great right now. I can restart and configure the server from webmin.

However, I would like to install `mod_wsgi` on `Apache` and to do this I should determine the path to `apxs` folder. However, in my apache installation, there is no `apxs` folder.

How can I install `mod_wsgi` module to Apache2.2 on Centos 5 ?
If there is no way to do that without giving path to `apxs`, how can I get `apxs` folder ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have installed `httpd-devel` such that

```
yum install httpd-devel.x86_64
```

After that `apxs` file is located at `/usr/sbin/`